# jQuery Increment Buttons Update Input Value Seen But Not Updating for Price Change

Tags: jquery, html

I added a plus & minus button in front of and behind my input for quantity and that works, the problem is that when the quantity gets updated, it's not updating the price/total, unless I click into and then back out of the input box. How do I get the quantity to update without needing to click into the input box?  The system already has code that will update the price when the quantity is changed but it's not reading the value being changed when I use the plus or minus button, only after I click in the box.

```js
$('input#w3934_txtQantity').before("<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='w3934_txtQantity' />");
$('input#w3934_txtQantity').after("<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='w3934_txtQantity' />");


$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('#w3934_txtQantity').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal + 10);
        } else {
            $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(0);
        }
    });
    $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
        var currentVal = parseInt($('#w3934_txtQantity').val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal - 10);
        } else {
            $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(0);
        }
  
    });
    
$('#w3934_txtQantity').trigger('change');
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;padding-top:5px;">
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblQuantity" style="white-space:nowrap;">Quantity</span></td><td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblUnitPrice" style="white-space:nowrap;">Unit Price</span></td>
<td><span id="w3934_lblAddlCharges" style="display:inline-block;width:110px;">Setup</span></td>
<td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblShip">Shipping</span></td><td valign="bottom" style="text-align:right;"><span id="w3934_lblSubTotal" style="white-space:nowrap;">Subtotal</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtQantity" type="text" value="170" id="w3934_txtQantity" class="medText formField" style="text-align:right;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtUnitPrice" type="text" value="$2.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtUnitPrice" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtAddlCharges" type="text" value="$55.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtAddlCharges" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtShip" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtShip" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine" align="right"><input name="w3934$txtSubTotal" type="text" value="$395.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtSubTotal" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You did not add any code that updates the total.

Comment: That's what `change` does, it fires when there's a change, i.e. when the focus leaves. If you want "live" updates you'd replace `change` with `input`

Comment: @adeneo what do you mean by "live" updates?

Comment: I mean that if you want the event to fire when the user changes the value without losing focus, you'd use the `input` event. You seem to have click events on something that probably updates a value, and you'd have to trigger the `change` event on clicks as well.

Comment: So instead of click I'd use input?  ... I think I'm starting to confuse myself.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the code for updating the total, but seeing that you trigger the change event on page load, I assume you have a change handler. Then the solution is just to call that handler at every +/- button click:

```js
$('input#w3934_txtQantity').before("<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='w3934_txtQantity' />");
$('input#w3934_txtQantity').after("<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='w3934_txtQantity' />");


$('.qtyplus').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('#w3934_txtQantity').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal + 10);
    } else {
        $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(0);
    }
    $('#w3934_txtQantity').trigger('change'); // <----
});
$(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('#w3934_txtQantity').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
        $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal - 10);
    } else {
        $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(0);
    }
    $('#w3934_txtQantity').trigger('change'); // <----
});

// The change handler which I suppose you already have:
$('#w3934_txtQantity').change(function () {
    $('#w3934_txtSubTotal').val('$' + 
        (($('#w3934_txtQantity').val().replace(/\$/, '') * 
          $('#w3934_txtUnitPrice').val().replace(/\$/, '') +
          +$('#w3934_txtAddlCharges').val().replace(/\$/, '') +
          +$('#w3934_txtShip').val().replace(/\$/, '')
          ) || 0).toFixed(2)
    );
});
    
$('#w3934_txtQantity').trigger('change');
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><table cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;padding-top:5px;">
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblQuantity" style="white-space:nowrap;">Quantity</span></td><td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblUnitPrice" style="white-space:nowrap;">Unit Price</span></td>
<td><span id="w3934_lblAddlCharges" style="display:inline-block;width:110px;">Setup</span></td>
<td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblShip">Shipping</span></td><td valign="bottom" style="text-align:right;"><span id="w3934_lblSubTotal" style="white-space:nowrap;">Subtotal</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtQantity" type="text" value="170" id="w3934_txtQantity" class="medText formField" style="text-align:right;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtUnitPrice" type="text" value="$2.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtUnitPrice" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtAddlCharges" type="text" value="$55.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtAddlCharges" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtShip" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtShip" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine" align="right"><input name="w3934$txtSubTotal" type="text" value="$395.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtSubTotal" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So that would work if my unit price was static, but the unit price changes based on the quantity. I need a way for the quantity to update without needing to click into the box after using the plus or minus buttons.

Answer (score 0):

After breaking it down into parts I finally realized that the problem was with the focus. I added an input event that removed the focus from the input box:

```
var $input = $("#w3934_txtQantity");

$input.on('input', function() {
 $input.blur();
});
```

And triggered that input after the value was increased or decreased by clicking the appropriate button:

```
$('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal - 10).trigger("input");
```

Hopefully this helps someone else. Working Code Below.

```js
$('input#w3934_txtQantity').before("<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='w3934_txtQantity' />");
$('input#w3934_txtQantity').after("<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='w3934_txtQantity' />");

var $input = $("#w3934_txtQantity");

$input.on('input', function() {
  $input.blur();
});

$(document).on( 'click', '.qtyplus', function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('#w3934_txtQantity').val());
        // If is not undefined
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            // Increment
          $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal + 10).trigger("input");
            } else {
            // Otherwise put min quantity there
           $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(0);
        }
       
     });
     $(document).on( 'click', '.qtyminus', function(e) {
        // Stop acting like a button
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get its current value
        var currentVal = parseInt($('#w3934_txtQantity').val());
        // If it isn't undefined or its greater than 0
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            // Decrement one
         $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(currentVal - 10).trigger("input");
        } else {
            // Otherwise put min quantity there
            $('#w3934_txtQantity').val(0);
        }
    
    });
```

```css
input {
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblQuantity" style="white-space:nowrap;">Quantity</span></td><td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblUnitPrice" style="white-space:nowrap;">Unit Price</span></td>
<td><span id="w3934_lblAddlCharges" style="display:inline-block;width:110px;">Setup</span></td>
<td valign="bottom"><span id="w3934_lblShip">Shipping</span></td><td valign="bottom" style="text-align:right;"><span id="w3934_lblSubTotal" style="white-space:nowrap;">Subtotal</span></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtQantity" type="text" value="170" id="w3934_txtQantity" class="medText formField" style="text-align:right;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtUnitPrice" type="text" value="$2.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtUnitPrice" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtAddlCharges" type="text" value="$55.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtAddlCharges" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine"><input name="w3934$txtShip" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtShip" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;text-align:center;" /></td>
<td class="SubTotalLine" align="right"><input name="w3934$txtSubTotal" type="text" value="$395.00" readonly="readonly" id="w3934_txtSubTotal" class="medText formField DisplayTextBox" style="margin-top:5px;" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```